# Trouble with Simple Average Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, velocity

I have a *super simple* question on average velocity that either I am not setting up correctly, or is itself graded incorrectly in a huge online system used by thousands of students for a very long time.

I seriously doubt the later could go uncaught.

Here's the question:

> A car travels along a straight line at a constant speed of 40.0 mi/h for a distance d and then another distance d in the same direction at another constant speed. The average velocity for the entire trip is 31.5 mi/h.
>
> What is the constant speed with which the car moved during the second distance d?

And here's my work:

V<sub>0</sub> = 40.0 mph
Δx<sub>0</sub> = d

V<sub>1</sub> = ?
Δx<sub>1</sub> = d

V<sub>avg</sub> = 31.5 mph = ( 40.0 mph + V<sub>1</sub> ) / 2
63 mph = 40.0 mph + V<sub>1</sub>
63 mph - 40.0 mph = V<sub>1</sub>
**23 mph = V<sub>1</sub>**

I've done this calculation a few times, used multiple sources to verify V<sub>avg</sub> = ( V<sub>f</sub> - V<sub>i</sub> ) / 2 for constant acceleration, and even tried a few variations of the problem using different values from my book.

Stil no dice; the computer always marks my answers as "off by less than 10%".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform - Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average velocity is given by
$$
\bar v=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T v(t)\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{T}(v_1t_1+v_2t_2)
$$
where $t_1$ is the time spend on the first interval, $t_2$ is the time spend on the second one, and $T=t_1+t_2$.

Using
$$
v_1t_1=v_2t_2=d
$$
you get
$$
\bar v=2\frac{v_1v_2}{v_1+v_2}
$$

I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Note that you cannot use $\bar v=\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}$. For example, if in your problem the car drives for 1 hour at $20\ \mathrm{mi/h}$, and then just one second at $40\ \mathrm{mi/h}$, then $\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}=30\ \mathrm{mi/h}$, which is not the average velocity (which is actually vero close to $20\ \mathrm{mi/h}$). The formula $\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}$ is **average over distance**, but what you want to calculate is **average over time**.